# How to check the value of Auxiliary Flag in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to know if the Auxiliary Flag is set or not ?
How I can do it in Assembly.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Use `lahf` (load AH from flags) followed by `test` (to check the value):

```
lahf
test   ah, 10h
jnz    .aux_nonzero
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to push the flags register onto the stack (`pushf`), then pop it off into a general purpose register (`pop ax` for example), and inspect the bits in `ax`.

Comment: good idea......but I behaved. I needed it to know if the 5th bit is set or not after add operation.
simple solution that I shift left 4 times and check the value of the carry

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [site](http://www.sandpile.org) which details comprehensive assembly instruction sets for the x86 architecture.

dang **gregh** you beat me to it... oh well....

It's the fourth bit that represents the Auxiliary Flag (AF)... as shown [here](http://www.sandpile.org/ia32/eflags.htm)